# Grab onto / around

Tags: prepositions

What would be the preposition after "grab" ?

Like, "Grab __ the support" .

I've encountered the use of "onto". Besides, my assumption is "around". Is it correct?

Comment: "Around" could be used, but wouldn't be typical for something of small diameter like a support bar on a train.  To me, "around" summons an image of something that you have to stretch to reach around, like a large pillar that you are wrapping your arms all the way around.  If it's just a bar that you're grabbing with your hand, I would always say "grab onto."

Answer (score 1):

In the case of grabbing a support, you don't necessarily need a preposition.

> Grab the support

and

> Grab onto the support

both sound perfectly fine to my ear.